# Arc lifetime does not live long enough from clone()

Tags: thread-safety, rust

I'm trying to create a parameter structure that will possibly be shared between threads. It has a member called `layer_storage` which some members will need to mutate. I tried the following code, but am getting an error saying that the cloned `Arc` does not live long enough. This same member worked fine before the addition of `Arc<Mutex<>>`.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Params {
    pub optional: Vec<f32>,
}

pub struct ParamManager {
    layer_storage: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Params>>>,
}

impl Default for ParamManager {
    fn default() -> ParamManager {
        ParamManager {
            layer_storage: Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![Params { optional: vec![1.0f32, 2.0f32] },
                                                    Params { optional: vec![3.0f32, 4.0f32] }])),
        }
    }
}

impl ParamManager {
    pub fn get_mut_params(&mut self, layer_index: usize) -> &mut Params {
        let layers_arc = self.layer_storage.clone();
        let layers = layers_arc.get_mut().unwrap();
        // tried this initially:
        // let layers = self.layer_storage.clone().get_mut().unwrap();
        assert!(layers.len() - 1 >= layer_index);
        &mut layers[layer_index]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bla = ParamManager::default();
    let i = bla.get_mut_params(0);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=93b3b4eb62cae98f47fac660563e47ef&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Comment: Did you try to assign the clone to a variable, then do the rest in a separate statement?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did: self.layer_storage.clone() and then work with that as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shepmaster says you can't just return a reference to something inside the `Arc<Mutex<T>>` from the `get_mut_params`; this is one of the guarantees you get from them!

One solution which works in may cases is to turn the function inside out; rather than returning a mutable reference, take a closure which is given the mutable reference:

```
impl ParamManager {
    pub fn with_mut_params<F>(&mut self, layer_index: usize, mut f: F)
                     where F: FnMut(&mut Params) {
        let layers_arc = self.layer_storage.clone();
        let layers = layers_arc.lock().unwrap();
        f(&mut layers[layer_index]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bla = ParamManager::default();

    // Context used by the closure
    let some_var: i32 = 7;
    let other_var: mut MyContext = do_something();

    bla.with_mut_params(0, |i| {
       // do stuff with i
       ...
       // A closure has access to surrounding variables
       other_var.foo(i, some_var);
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a pretty elegant way to handle the problem. Only issue I see here is the generalizability: i.e. the closure only accepts one parameter. If some context were needed this might not work as well (especially since rust doesn't have overloading).

Comment: Being a closure rather than just a function pointer means it can include context. Can you give an example that shows what might not be possible?

Comment: Since you have `where F: FnMut(&mut Params)` the only type of acceptable closure would be one that takes in just `&mut Params`, correct? Supposing a function would need a few, eg: `where F: FnMut(&mut Params)` **and** where `F: FnMut(&mut Params, &MyContext, i32)` it would need two different overloaded ops for this which is not possible (without a bunch of `Optional<>` 's which is a little ugly

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show how a closure solves that, as a comment is too short.

Comment: I think I realize! Did a quick read from the rust book. It takes into account local scope as well!

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler is right in your case.

There are two obvious errors here:

1. The `layers_arc` value lives just until the block end, and then it's destructor will decrement the reference counter and maybe drop the whole value. Or it could be dropped in other thread in any time. So it is illegal to return a pointer to it's contents.
2. `Mutex::get_mut` method requires `&mut self`, while it is impossible to get it directly from `Arc`.

So you have to refactor your code somehow. For example, you could guard each separate item in vector with `Arc<Mutex>` and return them by value using `.clone()`.

Comment: Thank you @swizard. This is a valid answer as well. Just decided to go with  the one below for cleanliness.