# Calling method on Trait object behind Arc & Mutex

Tags: rust

This [playground project](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1c57c05b8f306cbe2083858a8c2ebb18&version=stable) has a simplified version of the code I'm trying to compile.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};

pub trait Runnable {
    fn run(&mut self) -> Option<String>;
}

pub struct Value {}

impl Runnable for Value {
    fn run(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        Some("Value".to_string())
    }
}

pub struct RunList {
    runnables: Vec<Arc<Mutex<Runnable>>>,
}

impl RunList {
    pub fn run<R>(&mut self, index: usize, mut runner: R)
    where
        R: FnMut(&mut MutexGuard<Runnable>),
    {
        let runnable_arc = self.runnables[index].clone();
        let mut runnable = runnable_arc.lock().unwrap();
        runner(&mut runnable);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut runnables = Vec::<Arc<Mutex<Runnable>>>::with_capacity(1);
    runnables.push(Arc::new(Mutex::new(Value {})));

    let mut run_list = RunList { runnables };

    run_list.run(0, |runnable| {
        println!("Hello, {}", runnable.run().unwrap());
    });
}
```

I want a vector of trait objects, where each object is protected by an `Arc` and a `Mutex`, and then to be able to call a trait method on each object.

I have a "borrowed value does not live long enough" error but I can't see the difference from [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379952/arc-lifetime-does-not-live-long-enough-from-clone).

```
error[E0597]: `runnable_arc` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:25:28
   |
25 |         let mut runnable = runnable_arc.lock().unwrap();
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
26 |         runner(&mut runnable);
27 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

Comment: The error given by your simplified playground code is not the same error that you've posted in the question. Perhaps your playground example has been simplified too much?

Comment: `R: FnMut(&mut MutexGuard<Runnable>)` is the same as `R: FnMut(&mut MutexGuard<Runnable + 'static>)`.  You want `R: for <'a> FnMut(&mut MutexGuard<Runnable + 'a>)`

Comment: @Shepmaster If you write `R: FnMut(&mut MutexGuard<Runnable + 'static>)` though, the code compiles fine.

Comment: @Francis Cagné indeed it does! Now I'll go and study why! :-) If you want to submit an answer I'll accept it. If not, thanks anyway!

Comment: The problem was wierder than I expected. In my example I stripped out a later call after "runner(...)". In my real code it continued to fail until I did a deref on that code line which is AFTER the line the compiler was reporting the error on. I'll probably post a new playground example to illustrate when I get a moment. Adding a deref to the *subsequent* line fixed it!

Comment: @FrancisGagné interesting — reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be running into a glitch in the compiler's inference system. Changing `MutexGuard<Runnable>` to `MutexGuard<Runnable + 'static>` fixes the error:

```
impl RunList {
    pub fn run<R>(&mut self, index: usize, mut runner: R)
    where
        R: FnMut(&mut MutexGuard<Runnable + 'static>),
    {
        let runnable_arc = self.runnables[index].clone();
        let mut runnable = runnable_arc.lock().unwrap();
        runner(&mut runnable);
    }
}
```

But interestingly, changing it to `MutexGuard<'static, Runnable + 'static>` preserves the error:

```
impl RunList {
    pub fn run<R>(&mut self, index: usize, mut runner: R)
    where
        R: FnMut(&mut MutexGuard<'static, Runnable + 'static>),
    {
        let runnable_arc = self.runnables[index].clone();
        let mut runnable = runnable_arc.lock().unwrap();
        runner(&mut runnable);
    }
}
```

Why would the compiler infer the latter rather than the former? Well, let's look at the definition of [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html):

```
pub struct MutexGuard<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> { /* fields omitted */ }
```

In `MutexGuard<Runnable>`, `Runnable` is a trait object and gets an implicit `+ 'static` bound because there are no explicit lifetimes. It seems that the compiler tries to unify both occurrences of `'a` by reasoning that, if we need to replace the second occurrence with `'static`, then we need to do the same with the first occurrence. However, that logic forgets an important detail: `'static` outlives any lifetime `'a`, so there's no reason to force the first `'a` to be `'static`. Indeed, when we write `MutexGuard<Runnable + 'static>`, that's the same as `MutexGuard<'a, Runnable + 'static>` (how `'a` is defined depends on the context). That's valid because `Runnable + 'static: 'a` (you can always pass an object with some lifetime `'x` as an argument to a function that expects a *shorter* lifetime `'y`).

---

For the record, the issue has nothing to do with the `FnMut` trait; a normal function also shows this behavior:

```
impl RunList {
    pub fn run(&mut self, index: usize) {
        fn runner2(runnable: &mut MutexGuard<Runnable>) {
            println!("Hello, {}", runnable.run().unwrap());
        }

        let runnable_arc = self.runnables[index].clone();
        let mut runnable = runnable_arc.lock().unwrap();
        runner2(&mut runnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a reference to the `MutexGuard` to your `runner` instead of a reference to the wrapped runnable. You need to insert a deref:

```
pub fn run<R>(&mut self, index: usize, mut runner: R)
where
    R: FnMut(&mut Runnable),
{
    let runnable_arc = self.runnables[index].clone();
    let mut runnable = runnable_arc.lock().unwrap();
    runner(&mut *runnable);
}
```

From my understanding, this construct - `&mut *` - shouldn't be necessary here, because `MutexGuard` implements the `DerefMut` trait. Apparently, this is a known issue: [Why does a mutable borrow of a closure through DerefMut not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46472082)

Comment: I understand that since MutexGuard implements Deref and DerefMut, that is done for you by the compiler. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html   Although, I actually prefer to make things more explicit and quite like your suggestion.